# Using get_bloginfo('template_directory') or variable - performance issue

Tags: php, performance

Can I please ask you about the performance of these two approaches in term of execution speed and server load?

**approach 1:**

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/data1/images/1.jpg">
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/data1/images/2.jpg" />
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/data1/images/3.jpg" />
```

**approach 2:**

```
<?php $variable= get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $variable; ?>/data1/images/1.jpg">
<img src="<?php echo  $variable; ?>/data1/images/2.jpg" />
<img src="<?php echo $variable; ?>/data1/images/3.jpg" />
```

The answer to this question will be very useful for me since I meet such cases many times during Wordpress developement. Is the time to get variable content less than the time querying the database for blog info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference, because the result of `get_bloginfo()` comes from an internal cache anyway, because most (all?) of the return values come from `get_option()` calls, and these are cached internally with `wp_cache_set()` and fetched with `wp_cache_get()`. See [Exploring the WordPress Cache API](http://wptip.me/wordpress-cache-api).

Even if there would be a difference it would be too small to be relevant.

The more important difference is readability. This is easier to read and less error prone:

```
$template_dir = get_template_directory_uri(); 

foreach ( array ( 1, 2, 3 ) as $n )
    echo "<img src='$template_dir/data1/images/$n.jpg' alt=''>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. let me please ask you a question. Could you please give me some additional info about this internal cache? is it server side or client side? what I know is that caching may depend on server installed caching systems (like memechached for example), reverse proxies, or headers responses obliging the browser to cache. Does Wordpress force browser to cache?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I made an update to my answer. The internal cache exists for the current request only, it is limited, but good enough for your use case.

Comment: It is the first time I hear about `wp_cache_set()`, I am reading about it, and frankly, it will be highly appreciated if I have a link talking about this (limited) cache and alternatives. the `get_bloginfo` function was only a simple exmple to trigger big learning about wordpress performance and caching in the case of high concurrency websites. Thanks agains

Comment: I have added a useful link. :)

Comment: :-P and you are using `get_template_directory_uri();`  instead of `get_bloginfo('template_directory');`!! An expert like you will not change the function for no reason!!! Anyway  I used your function instead of mine

Comment: `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` is just a wrapper for the real function.